Transforming portfolios when transforming factors
This should be a relatively simple, mostly linear algebra question. It starts with factors, let's say 50 of them. Each factor has a time series of returns, let's say 250, and an associated portfolio of assets, let's say 1000. The factor returns get whitened and then transformed into a fewer number of secondary factors, let's say 10, using a transformation matrix.
Here are relevant matrices:
X (250, 50) - factor returns
P (1000, 50) - factor portfolios (unit norm for each factor)
xmeans (50) - a vector of means for each time series (to center them)
W (50, 50) - the whitening matrix
T (50, 10) - the transformation matrix
Z (250, 10) - secondary factor returns
R (1000, 10) - secondary factor portfolios <--- to compute

so that Z = (X - xmeans) * W * T
The question is, how to transform the original portfolio matrix into a corresponding secondary portfolio matrix (so that the portfolio returns from both representations - X with P, Z with R - are the same for any given time step)?
